# Set of all sets those are equipotent to a given set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, alternative-proof

> Two sets are said to be 'equipotent' if there is a bijection between them. For a given set $A,$ consider the class $\Bbb{A}$ of all sets those are equipotent with $A.$ Is $\Bbb{A}$ form a set?

My answer is "No" unless $A=\emptyset.$ In order to prove this, my idea is to use the fact that class of all singleton sets is not a set.

1) Is my conclusion correct?
2) Is there any better (direct) way to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conclusion is right.

There are several ways to prove it, and I'm not entirely sure which one you have in mind based on your idea, but here's a hint that follows that idea: what is the cardinality of $\{x\}\times A$, for any set $x$?

Comment: My idea is, if $A$ is non-empty, then $(A\setminus\{a\})\cup\{x\}$ is equipotent with $A$ for any singleton $\{x\}$ and some $a\in A.$ But your idea is way clear than it.